# Conflic with shared React custom hook and window.onscroll property

Tags: reactjs, window, react-hooks

I've a React custom hook that shows/hidden a button according to window.pageYOffset values:

```js
const useHandlerOnScroll = height => {

    const [buttonVisible, showUpButton] = useState(false);
    useEffect ( () => {
        window.onscroll = () => {
            window.pageYOffset >= height ? showUpButton(true) : showUpButton(false)
        }
    })  

    return { buttonVisible }
}
```

Whenever I need to use it I just deconstruct my hook in my component and take the buttonVisible value:

```js
export default () => {

    const { buttonVisible } = useHandlerOnScroll(450)

    const goTop = () => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })

    return buttonVisible 
      ? <BottoneTop onClick={() => }> <FaChevronCircleUp /> </BottoneTop> 
        : null
}
```

This procedure works as long as I use it only for one component, if I export my useHandlerOnScroll hook and use it on another button then only one button shows up.

I don't understand why, since I thought that every component that imports the hook will create a new instance of that hook.

I also tried useReducer but the result is the same: I canno't use the hook with more than one component.

PS: my guess is that the window.oncroll property is causing some conflict when called like that (I still would prefer not to use addEventListener due to performance reasons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered that `.onscroll` method can only be asigned one object at time, so that's the origin of the conflict:

> Only one onscroll handler can be assigned to an object at a time. For greater flexibility, you can pass a scroll event to the EventTarget.addEventListener() method instead.

from: [MDN Web docs - GlobalEventHandlers.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)

I fixed my problem with `window.addEventListener("scroll", callbackFunction )`.